# Cucmber Feature file execution from Maven CLI

Tags: maven, cucumber

I am trying to execute a cucumber feature file from maven command line and facing the following issue - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project Maven: No tests were executed!

The command I have used to execute is - 
mvn -Dtest -Document.options="src/test/resources/maven_poc/excel_colors.feature:3"

However the step definitions file is executed successfully when executed from maven command prompt. 
•   mvn -Dtest=excel_color_stepdef test
Screenshot at the link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKsd8.jpg

My pom.xml is as below. Anyone who has faced similar issues? Any tips on resolution steps is appreciated.

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Cucumber_POC</groupId>
  <artifactId>Maven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  
<reporting>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.3</version>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</reporting>
  
 <build>
 <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>
       <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
          </configuration>
    </plugin>  
    
     <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
     </plugin>
     
     <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          </plugin>
          
          <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.1</version>
    </plugin>
    
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </plugin>
    
  </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>      
</build>
  
  <dependencies>
    
      <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>4.12</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    
       <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
    
       <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
    
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
     <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
        
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0</version>
         </dependency>
     
             
 </dependencies>
 
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Those don't look like valid maven commands. It's `mvn test`. And the system property is named `cucumber.options`. So `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/maven_poc/excel_colors.feature:3"`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried executing the command shared by you, but still gives the same error : Failed to execute goal - No tests executed.

Comment: Apologies, There is a correction in the outcome. Build is successful when mvn test -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/maven_poc/excel_colors.feature:3" is executed. But tests are not getting detected.

Comment: I don;'t know then. You could try this project: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton it's known to work. Then change it into your project until it stop working and see where you go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the java test class that references the cucumber. Something like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class, classes = EligibilityApplication.class)
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/cucumber/eligibility/listpolicies/ListPolicies.feature", strict = true)
public class ListPoliciesTest {

}
```

And in the maven command you will use something like:

```
mvn -Dtest="src/test/java/../ListPoliciesTest.java"
```

Comment: Hi Alan, yes, you are right, the Step Definition file needs to be executed. I have executed the same successfully and it does execute the Tests as well. Issue reported is only when I try to execute the feature file from maven command prompt.